# Error using @Embedded Tag when setting up Room Database

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room, room

I am trying to use @Embedded in a data class in order to save subfields as columns in my Room Database.  When I try to run my app I get this error:

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

My Data Class looks like this:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "workorder",
    indices = [Index("order_number"), Index("customer_number")]
)
data class WorkorderResponse(

    @ColumnInfo(name = "acres")
    val acres: Double?,
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "order_number")
    val orderNumber: Int,
   ...
    @Embedded(prefix="application_")
    val orderApplication: OrderApplication,
)
```

The Order Application class looks like this:

```
data class OrderApplication(
    val acres: String?,
    val applicationMethod: String?,
    val carrier: String?,
    val cropHeight: Int?,
    val currentPrecip: Int?,
    val fieldConditions: String?,
    val loadSiteLat: Int?,
    val loadSiteLong: Int?,
    val loadingMethod: String?,
    val machine: String?,
    val method: String?,
    val nextDayPrecipAmount: Int?,
    val nextDayPrecipChance: Int?,
    val nextDayTemperature: Int?,
    val nextDayWeather: String?,
    val notes: String?,
    val notified: String?,
    val `operator`: Int?,
    val pressure: String?,
    val previousOrder: String?,
    val reEntryInterval: Int?,
    val rinsedPost: String?,
    val rinsedPrevious: String?,
    val rotateRest: String?,
    val sensitiveArea: String?,
    val sequence: Int?,
    val soilConditions: String?,
    val soilType: String?,
    val temperature: Int?,
    val tenderOperator: String?,
    val timestampBegin: String?,
    val timestampEnd: String?,
    val tipSize: String?,
    val weather: String?,
    val weedHeight: Int?,
    val windDirection: String?,
    val windSpeed: Int?,
    val wkt: String?
)
```

Is there something else I need to do in order to get this set up correctly?
Thanks in advance!

I've tried using a list like this:

```
    @Embedded(prefix="application_")
    val orderApplication: List<OrderApplication>,
```

but that gives me this error:

```
Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor.
```

Also, I have these Type Converters:

```
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromOrderApplication(orderApplication: List<OrderApplication>): String{
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<OrderApplication>>() {}.type
        return gson.toJson(orderApplication, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toOrderApplication(json: String): List<OrderApplication> {
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<OrderApplication>>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(json, type)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out how to get `@Embedded` to work.  I ended up just using type converters to store the OrderApplication data in one column as a JSON string.